# How do I repeat a hover function?

Tags: jquery, html

I am busy working on a timeline, I have the got the basic function working in jQuery see my jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jason1975/6nwkd2c8/38/

The problem is I am cannot repeat the hover. I am very new at jQuery and would really appreciate some guidance how to repeat the hover function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#next").hover(function(){
        $("li").animate({ "right" : "300px" }, "slow");
    });
    $("a#prev").hover(function(){
        $("li").animate({ "left" : "0" }, "slow");
    });   
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by `repeat the hover`? Can you describe your intended behaviour a little more clearly.

Comment: What do you mean by "repeat the hover function"? Hover is event which occur on your action.

Comment: currently if I hover once on the next arrow and once on the right arrow after both have have been triggered I cannot do it again and I need to be abler to hover repeatedly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With few small fixes, it [works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/6nwkd2c8/40/). Script changed to:

```
$("a#next").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#new").animate({
        "left": "+=200px"
    }, 200);
});
$("a#prev").mouseenter(function () {
    $("#new").animate({
        "left": "-=200px"
    }, 200);
});
```

and small CSS fix:

```
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#new {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#next, #prev {
    top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are first animating the `right` offset of the LIs, then animating the `left` offset. The end result is the item has both `left` and `right` set, so it cannot move.

Just animate one property/side back and forth: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/6nwkd2c8/39/

```
$("a#next").hover(function () {
    $("li").animate({
        "left": "300px"
    }, "slow");
});
$("a#prev").hover(function () {
    $("li").animate({
        "left": "0"
    }, "slow");
});
```

When in doubt, use the Chrome F12 DOM inspector to look at (and change) your elements, so you can *see* what is going on :)

Answer (score 1):

i think what you want to do is shift it further, which you can do via aimate like this:

```
$("a#next").hover(function () {
    $("li").animate({
        "left": "+=300px" //+= is the key
    }, "slow");
});
```

[EDIT] fumbling around with your fiddle tells me the actual answer is the mix of left/right, since if you set left=0, right will be ignored

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a#next").hover(function(){
        $("li").animate({ "right" : "+=300px" }, "slow");
    },function(){}); //empty function to prevent jQuery to use the first on leave too
    $("a#prev").hover(function(){
        $("li").animate({ "right" : "0" }, "slow");
    },function(){});  //empty function to prevent jQuery to use the first on leave too
});
```

Comment: your code fired twice 1st time occurs `'onmouseEnter'`    and 2nd time occurs when `'onMouseOut'`

Comment: obviously, jQuery uses the hover function as leave when no second function is defined